# Está Selecionando todos <li> com condicional Styling (React)

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Estou Com problema , estou desenvolvendo uma lista de tarefas em React , só que na hora de sublinhar tarefas , ele sublinha todas até as que não estão marcadas no checkbox

abaixo vou disponibilizar o código e o repositório do GitHub

Github: https://github.com/sajous/Lista-De-Tarefas

```
import { Button, Checkbox } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect} from "react"
import { FaTrash , FaEdit} from 'react-icons/fa'
import './home.css'



export const Home = (props :any) => {


    const [item, setItem]:any = useState('');
    const [itemList, setItemList]:any = useState([])
    const [check , setCheck] :any = useState()

    const addItem = () => {
        if( item.length === 0) return;
        setItemList([item].concat(itemList))
        setItem('')
    }

    const handleKeyPress = (e:any) => {
        if(e.key === 'Enter'){
            if(e.currentTarget.value.trim().length === 0) return;
            setItemList([item].concat(itemList))
            setItem('')
        }
      }

      const teste =(e:any) =>{
        
        setCheck(!check)
      }

    
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Minhas Tarefas</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Item" value={item} name="item" onChange = {e => setItem(e.target.value)} onKeyDown={handleKeyPress} />
        <Button variant="text" className="Button" onClick={addItem}>➕</Button>
      <ul>
        {itemList.map((item:any, index:any) => (
          <li><Checkbox checked={check} onChange={teste} inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }} /><div id={index} className={`sublinhado ${check ? 'sublinhado-activate' : 'sublinhado-desactivate'}`}>{item}</div><a href=""><FaTrash /></a> <a href=""><FaEdit /></a></li>
        ))}
      </ul>
         </div>
    )
        
}
```

```
.container{
    
    background-color: #e3e3e3 ;
    margin: 10px 200px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px;
}

h1{
    padding-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

input {
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 23%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 1px ;
    font-size: 20px;
    
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-right:10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    float: right ;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.sublinhado-desactivate{
    text-decoration: initial;
    text-align: center;
}

.sublinhado-activate{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

O problema é que você está selecionando a classe nas `<li>` de acordo com o valor "check" do estado. Quando você clica em qualquer checkbox, o valor de "check" vira "true", e é aplicada em todas as tags `<li>` a classe 'sublinhado-activate'.